# fabricjs cannot access local variables in callback of loadFromJSON, etc

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I have such code using fabricjs.

```
var jsonStr = $stateElement.getAttribute('data-operation-state');
fabricCanvas.loadFromJSON(jsonStr, function(){
  console.log(jsonStr);
  console.log($stateElement);
});
```

then it will cause an error says jsonStr and $stateElement is not defined. Do you know why?

Comment: Make a snippet/fiddle stating the issue

Comment: It is solved, I find if I write the code in the function, the reference is ok, but when I set a breakpoint and access the variable in console, it will cause such a question.